# Amazon S3 + Jcrop Cropping Images

Tags: php, jquery, amazon-s3

I have an S3 account and can view images I manually put up there.

Also I have done image cropping with Jcrop before.

I need to now join the 2 - eg: crop an image and then have the final image reside on S3.

Questions:

- in the past the user selects an image and its uploaded to the server. This image then appears in the cropper and the user crops it. At this point I assume I could use the S3.php script to move the script to amazon and then delete the original instance and cropped instance of the file off my server. Is this the best way to get a cropped file up there?
- I read a little about people not needing to save a copy of the file to there server and still getting a cropped version onto S3. Is this possible? Does this just mean they work off the php/server/temp instance of the image and never save it to the server?

Any other advise would be greatly appreciated...

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access member variables in an object using another variable as name:

$element; // prints "aMemberVar Member Variable" 
?>

or use functions: